# Unexpected result when querying ignite with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, ignite

I have a table stored in ignite:

| date | id | info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2023-07-03" | a | ... |
| "2023-07-03" | a | ... |
| "2023-07-03" | a | ... |
| "2023-07-04" | a | ... |
| "2023-07-04" | a | ... |
| "2023-07-04" | a | ... |

now I query ignite with the sql:

```
select date, count(*) from table 
where id in (a, b) 
and date between "2023-07-03" and "2023-07-04" 
group by date
```

where the id "b" has no data in the table as you can see.

I expected to get the result:

"2023-07-03", 3 
"2023-07-04", 3

but actually I get

"2023-07-03", 6 
"2023-07-04", 6

I'm not sure if I miss any configuration or else, but this case occurs when I use "group by" and "id in (...)" together.

(P.S. I use gridgain-community:8.8.25)

Comment: You sure? Works ok here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e47f3/3/0

Comment: yeah it works well if I query big query, but not for ignite...not sure if it's a different syntax for ignite supported sql

Comment: Try querying a single field rather than `*` -- IE `count(id)`

Comment: I tried both count(date) and count(id) even with restriction "IS NOT NULL", but still the same result :(

Comment: How many server nodes do you have in the cluster? Also, please provide the cache configuration or create table statement, that was used for the `table` creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN ('a', 'b') 
AND date BETWEEN DATE '2023-07-03' AND DATE '2023-07-04' 
GROUP BY date
```